# How to Convert float to Char * in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, char, type-conversion

I am trying to convert to float to int

```
float flot=2.1456;
char*  c [] = {(char *)flot};
ObjLen = sizeof(c)/sizeof(*c);
NSLog(@"ObjLen %d",ObjLen);
```

but it is showing error **Operand of type 'float' cannot be cast to a pointer type**

and **Converting Char* to back again to float**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly convert float to NSString

```
float flot=2.1456;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%f",flot];
```

Use -[NSString UTF8String]: to convert to char *

```
const char *c = [str UTF8String]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better way is using `sprintf` or `snprintf` methods from `stdio.h`. `sprintf/snprintf` 2x faster than @Prince approach.